# need some help from count query

Tags: mysql

I have a table called

`tb_applicants` with fields `id`, `aic`, `name`

`app_interview` with fields `id`, `atic`, `atname`

My problem is i want to count all (`atic`) from `app_interview` table where `atic` is equal to `aic` from table (`tb_applicants`) group by 1(`aic`) from `tb_applicants`

In my current query its not working can anyone help me find where is the problem it gives me 0 count all the time.

**query:**

```
SELECT count(t.atic) 
FROM app_interview as t 
INNER JOIN tb_applicants as t2 
WHERE t.atic = t2.aic 
GROUP BY t2.aic;
```

Comment: why do you have " ; " after WHERE t.atic = t2.aic;  ?

Comment: i remove it but it still not working

Comment: not wokring :( gives 0 all the time

Comment: create a sqlfiddle.com link with sample data

Comment: @Damodaran is right, if you provide tables' scheme, and what do you want to count, will be clear. For instance maybe you have to count with this: `SELECT count(t.aic) 
FROM tb_applicants as t
INNER JOIN app_interview as t2 
WHERE t.aic = t2.atic 
GROUP BY t.aic`. I'am trying to say that maybe you have connect tables  in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could probably done simpler, since you need only matching rows:

```
SELECT count(t.atic) 
FROM app_interview as t, tb_applicants as t2 
WHERE t.atic = t2.aic 
GROUP BY t.atic;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` and use `ON` for JOINS:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM app_interview INNER JOIN tb_applicants ON tb_applicants.aic = app_interview.atic GROUP BY tb_applicants.aic;
```